# PHP negative lookahead regex not working

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to construct a regex in my PHP application that takes a variable, such as `$search`, and replaces that with another variable.  What I am trying to do specifically, is replace the `$search` value only if it is not followed directly by an `=`.

What I have tried so far is:

```
preg_replace("/($search)(?!=)/i", $replacement, $string, -1, $count);
```

But this has not worked.  I'm sure I am just misunderstanding something, but I can not seem to determine what that is.  I am fairly new to regex, and I've looked at several of the answers from previous questions and have not been able to figure it out.

If you need any other information, let me know.

**EDIT**

To clarify, assume the following code:

```
$searchTerm = "Hello";
$search = "/($searchTerm)(<?!=)/i";
$replacement = '<span style="background:red;">$0</span>';
$result = preg_replace($search, $replacement, $string, -1, $count);
```

where the value of $string would be something like:

```
$string = "hello=hola";
```

So the idea is that if "hello" was not followed by and '=', then it would highlight it in red, but if it is, then nothing happens.  At assume that the value of $string can change.  Very lame example, I know, but hopefully it clears it up a little.

Comment: you need to escape your `$` -> `\$` and probably your `=` as well

Comment: @cmorrissey: No they need to use double quotes or concatenation for the var to be parsed.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single vs. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: I apologize.  I was using double quotes in my code, and messed it up upon copying it to here.  That part works fine, but it still matches the value of $search even when followed by an '='.

Comment: What is `$search` then? Note that without anchors, lookarounds do not usually prevent from partial matches. Anyway, I'd recommend `preg_quote`ing the `$search` if it is a literal. `preg_replace("/" . preg_quote($search, "/") . "(?!=)/i", $replacement, $string, -1, $count);`

Comment: I want to search for the value of $search, which is set earlier in the code, and can change.

Comment: Okay, so post a reproducible example where we can see the issue, not reproducible here; https://eval.in/589945.

Comment: To make it more simple, edit your post with the value (or several possible values) of `$search` and show how looks the string. For now, two answers have been posted for nothing (based on wrong assumptions).

Comment: Your example, https://eval.in/589950, doesn't have the negative look ahead. With that no match, https://eval.in/589951.

Comment: Your update should throw `Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 11`. Please copy and paste the actual code you are having an issue with..

Comment: Worse, in the updated scenario, the [regex won't find any match](https://regex101.com/r/xY5eI5/1). Thus, it "won't work", i.e. the string will remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to escape `$` character by a backslash `\` in your pattern. Also to make it more confident, you can add `\s*` which means zero or more white space(s) before `=` character.

Use this pattern:

```
/\$search(?!\s*\=)/i
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gJ3nJ2/2)

- `/` delimiter
- `\$` matches `$` literally
- `search` matches that word literally
- `(?!`  negative Lookahead which checks being both white space(s) *(if exists)* and `=` after that variable name.
- `/i` modifire makes the pattern insensitive *(there isn't any different between `a-z` and `A-Z`)*

**Note:** You have to use single quotes `'/pattern/'` for pattern above. If you want to use double quotes `"` then you should escape backslashes again:

```
/\\$search(?!\\s*\\=)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$` is an anchor in regex to match the end of a line, so since it's a special character you have to escape it.

You can use:

```
preg_replace("/(\\$search)(?!=)/i", $replacement, $string, -1, $count);
```

or

```
preg_replace('/(\$search)(?!=)/i', $replacement, $string, -1, $count);
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kF3xK0/1)**